# open visual studio using php

Tags: php, visual-studio-2012, user-interface

Can someone tell how can Visual Studio be opened using PHP command? I can open a PHP webpage using cmd file in Visual Studio using C# script, but unable to start visual studio through a PHP command.

Can we also compile and run a C# program in Visual Studio through PHP command?

Comment: Check the PHP Manual for `exec()` , `system()`.

Comment: Thanxx. Can we also compile and run a C# program in Visual Studio through PHP command?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
exec("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"); // or the path to your Visual Studio Installation
```

Please remember, exec will execute the command line on the server side

Comment: Thanxx. Can we also compile and run a C# program in Visual Studio through PHP command?

Comment: you could run any command line program using PHP's exec function. Here is the documentation http://in1.php.net/function.exec